# How to upload java application which is already made?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I was searching for an answer to this question but i found only google app engine (I am not saying it is not working with that but i could not make it yet using GAE). So to be more clear: I want to make some portfolio of my applications on some of my websites.

So everything i want to do is to upload somehow normal Java applications to make them run for the people visiting my website.

The problem is that applications are not applets nor web applications and they are all made in NetBeans IDE 7.3.1. I ve already tried GAE guest book and it is working but i have no clue how to continue (i created an application    but how to upload it there? some tutorials are saying to deploy it using GAE but this option is not there after left clicking on the project). 
Thank you for any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java Web Start. This let users run your Java application from your website. However, they need to have Java installed on their computers.

Comment: Thanks it looks great and would you mind telling me what will be the difference among normal applications using java web start and applets and web applications please? Thank you.

Comment: @Ondrej'zatokar'Tokár Applets, by default, exist as a rectangle within a web page, although they can also open their own windows. Web applications run on one or more web servers, and send HTML and Javascript to the web browser.